# Call DB stored procedure with xml input in MobileFirst javascript adapter

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

I have a use case, which requires the javascript adapter to call a SOAP service and then to call a DB stored procedure. 
The SOAP service returns a list in xml format, which needs to be passed along into the DB stored procedure.

My challenge is DB stored procedure requires the xml input, but within the MF adapter the SOAP response comes back as JSON.

1. What is the best way to solve this within MF adapter, assuming i cannot change SOAP and DB stored procedure.
2. Is it possible to obtain raw xml in SOAP service call within MF javascript adapter?
3. Is it possible to use third party json to xml converters in javascript adapters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 adapters, the first one invoked by the client but before returning the response back to the client use the response from the invocation of the SOAP service and invoke another adapter on the server side passing in the XML response. On the call to SOAP service, you can control the response to be returned back in XML. It is only when the response is returned to the client (device) is when it is automatically converted to JSON.